# Overwriting __pycache__ in runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching

I have a python3 script, let's call it `script.py` which imports from other python files from the same directory, thus it creates a `__pycache__` folder when it's ran. From what I understand this cache is a binary compiled version of those imported files to make them execute faster.

I execute the `script.py` from the terminal, so it creates those cache files, and it runs the script which will run for some time. Now what happens if I edit the `script.py` file, change some parameters, and run it again from a second terminal while the first one is still running. This will create a different cache, it will overwrite that folder from what I understand. But will this interfere with the calculations from the first instance that is already running?

What I mean is that will the first instance continuously read that cache file after it's executed (thus reading the wrong newly modified parameters) or it only reads it once as loads it into the memory at the moment of launch?

Will the second modified script interfere with the first one or are they completely isolated?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you change the content of `script.py`, new cache won't be generated. The cache is really just your code, that has been compiled. It doesn't contains any run-time data, etc. and thus importing it into different terminals should not affect the others whatsoever. If you don't want Python to generate that cache, you can use [PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE), but it will really just make your module slightly slower to import as it will need to be recompiled every times.

Comment: That's not what I was asking. I was worried whether the 1st instance would read the wrong data at runtime from the cache while the 2nd instance runs a modified version. If in the first instance, in the script, the variable `a=1` then if I change the script so `a=2`, will the first instance now read the cache and also set `a=2` or will it ignore any change to the file and just use the preloaded version of it from the memory. I am worried about the 2nd modified instance overwriting the computation in the memory of the 1st instance!